# How to receive data from ajax send() method in a controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to serve the data in the ASP.NET MVC controller sent by ajax POST. On client side I use traditional XMLHttpRequest object and send() method instead of jQuery.ajax().

Do you know how to get variables from send() in controller? In documentation http://www.xul.fr/XMLHttpRequest-object.html I've read that it has to be string.

My client-side:

```
    var data1 = "some string";
    var data2 = "other string";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "https://localhost:44301/Home/SaveDataInDB", true);
    xhr.send(data1, data2);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = saved;
```

My server-side:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveDataInDB(string data1, string data2) 
    {
        var dbobj = new DbObj
        {                
            field1 = data1,
            field2 = data2
        };

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            dbobj.user = User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else 
        {
            dbobj.user = "anonymous";
        }


        db.DbObj.Add(dbobj);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this, lets say this is your xmlHttpRequest -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var o = new Object();
    o.data1 = "Rami";
    o.data2 = "Ramilu";

    request.open('POST', '/Home/xhr', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', JSON.stringify(o).length);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send(JSON.stringify(o));
</script>
```

On the server side, have a ViewModel defined this way -

```
public class XhrViewModel
{
    public string data1 { get; set; }
    public string data2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then your controller action which want to get this data -

```
    public ActionResult xhr(XhrViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("success", "text/plain");
    }
```

And the output would be -

[image]

Comment: No, that isn't what I meant. I'd like to use data1 and data2 variables in the controller. How to properly pass them?

Comment: @magos, I updated my complete answer. Please check it.

Comment: Well... It seems it should work, but I still have got a problem. In controller, I inserted breakpoint as you did, and in my app model/data1 and data2 are null. What can be reason? 

Let me understand where and when data from client-side script are passing to ViewModel? Because from XhrViewModel are derived in controller... Want you see my implementation again?

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry - I applied other o-object names than in ViewModel. :) Your answear is great. Thank you!